# Copy the duplicate records in MVC using Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new in MVC Entity Framework.

I have one Table called Product. it contain 40 fields.

I have one task to copy the Product or to create the duplicate record in same table with new Product ID..

How can I do this in efficient ways?

I tried using the below code

```
Public ActionResult CopyProduct(long ProductID)
{
var oldProductScript = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ProductID == ProductID)


Product p = new Product();
p.name = oldProductScript.name;
p.price =oldProductScript.price;
p.model =oldProductScript.model;
p.image = oldProductScript.image;
p.status =oldProductScript.status;
.
.
.
.
.
like so till 40th field

db.Products.AddObject(p);
db.SaveChanges();
```

}

Is this the proper way to complete this task?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: It might be better to do the task in the stored procedure of the database I think...

Comment: I think the question is related to the C# code needed to copy the product. I suggest you to use an external library like AutoMapper that will do the perfect copy, with your custom behavior if needed, of the product. Hope this can help: http://automapper.org/

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects. Would that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be done much easier(reduced coding), I would recommend you to use Code First Approach.
Use this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx) to know what is it and code sample.

After you add the tables with models(DBContext) as using Code First Approach, you would be able to easily get and set properties of the table even faster than your usual method.

```
public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableName> TableProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Use a polymorphic query to retrieve the fields of the table.

```
IQueryable<TableName> linqQuery = from b in context.TableName select b;
List<TableName> tableFields = linqQuery.ToList();
```

linqQuery returns list of objects of the type

Comment: My project is already in Database First Approach.. What about attach and detach of entity object ?

Comment: @ajaysingh It may not be an efficient way. The object that is passed to the Attach method must have a valid EntityKey value. If the object does not have a valid EntityKey value, use the AttachTo method to specify the name of the entity set.

Comment: @ajaysingh - If you want to use Database First approach, you could clone the object or rather serialize and transfer as JSON. It will be a considerable way to solve performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        Products productToCopy = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productID);
        db.Entry(productToCopy).State = EntityState.Detached;
        productToCopy.ProductId = 0;
        db.Products.Add(productToCopy);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what is DXLEntities ??

Comment: yes, I assume the "db" in your code is a DBContext? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.entry(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: But Intellisense is not supporting db.Entry.Its showing db.GetEntry instead of what u suggested me.

Comment: what EF version are u using?

Comment: My EF version  6.0.0.0

Comment: Strange I use the same version and I just ran the Code...how is the db-variable declared?

Comment: I havnt used ObjectContext but maybe you can do something similar (get object, detach it and then add it as a new object again)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I've tested this with one of my classes and it worked. Not sure if it will work with yours:

```
var prod = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == ProductID);
var prod2 = new Products();
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in prod.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    prod2.GetType().GetProperties().First(p=>p.Name==pi.Name).SetValue(prod2, pi.GetValue(prod, null), null);
}

//prod2 is now a clone of prod. Make sure to adjust your product ID before adding the new product.
```